# My Grails Application cannot send SOAP Request to another Grails Application at its first runtime only

Tags: grails, soap

I have two grails application. (Master) and (Mediator)

(Master) sends SOAP Request to (Mediator). I created the SOAP Request logic in a grails service of (Master) and then execute it from a controller.
While my grails application (Master) is running fresh, the grails service containing SOAP Request returns java.io.FileNotFoundException.

I tried to edit the code of the Grails Service while running (by adding println or linespaces). After saving that grails service, SOAP logic did work.

I need my (Master) application that when I ran it for the first time, it should still can send SOAP Requests. I was trying to clean and compile both applications and even double checking its XSDs, Endpoints and Declarations on Config.groovy but it still doesnt work.